# AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'gpa'

Tags: python

I am currently having a problem with this error: AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'gpa'

When I try to run the following program.

```
class people(object):
    def __init__(self,name,ID):
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID

class Student(people):
    def __init__(self,name,ID,gpa):
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID
        self.gpa=gpa

Student.gpa.total.append(self.gpa)

def mean_gpa():
    return sum(Student.gpa_total)/float (len(Student.gpa_total))

def info_gpa(self):
    mean= self.mean_gpa()
    return mean
def __str__(self):
    return self.info_gpa()

class Employee(people):
    def __init__(self,name,ID,salary):
        people._init_(self,name,ID)`
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID
        self.salary=salary
        self.employee=employee
        Employee.emp_total.append(self.employee)`

def total_salary():
    return sum(Employee.emp_total)`
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please remove all the backticks from the code you've posted

Comment: Yes, `Student` is a class, where as `gpa` is a class instance attribute. Create an object of type student, and you can reference `gpa` attribute without any issues`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `Student.gpa` here:

```
Student.gpa.total.append(self.gpa)
```

<s>I'm not sure what that line is supposed to do, but you're trying to access it as a static variable (an attribute of the class, rather than of an instance of the class) when it doesn't exist. `__init__()` assigns a `gpa` attribute of `self`, which is an instance of `Student`, but that isn't what you're accessing. Also, `self` isn't defined outside of `__init__()`.</s>

---

Actually, I read your code again. It looks like you want something like this:

```
class Student(people):
    def __init__(self,name,ID,gpa):
        self.name=name
        self.ID=ID
        self.gpa=gpa
        try:
            Student.gpa_total.append(self.gpa)
        except AttributeError:
            Student.gpa_total=[self.gpa]
```

Comment: This may "work" (that is, not cause errors) but I think it will only further confuse the OP's understanding of instance vs. class attributes.  It's not clear *why* they want to use class attributes -- imho, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

A quick run through [pyflakes](https://github.com/pyflakes/pyflakes/) shows me these two errors:

1. line 12 : **undefined name `self`.**

   Hint: With the line `Student.gpa.total.append(self.gpa)`, you're referring to `self` outside of a class, so it's undefined.
2. line 29: **undefined name `employee`**. Inside the `Employee` class, `self.employee=employee`, you've set `self.employee` to a non-existent variable called `employee`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an instance of student on which you can use the method gpa.
i.e,

```
    student1=student("Tom",12345,3.8)
    student1.gpa()
```

to access the instance